# VS, C# Can't generate Service Reference for LoginService

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, soap-client

I am tasked with creating a SOAP client for an API using .NET Core 6.

Their instructions direct me to add a Service Reference in Visual Studio, for *LoginService*.  All they provide is this:

[image: API Instructions]

However, when I right click my project, and "*Add Service Reference*", all I have for options are:

1. OpenAPI
2. gRPC, and
3. WCF Web Service

Is "*LoginService*" just a name that I assign to something I create from one of these options?  Or is *LoginService* something else that is just missing in .NET Core 6?

Comment: what kind of service are you wanting to reference?

Comment: https://medium.com/compendium/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb

Comment: @DanielA.White That link looks very much like what I am trying to accomplish.  I will look at it tomorrow (late here, now).  I knew it would probably be one of those three options.  I should have suspected the WCF option.  Thanks

Comment: The problem is that other services cannot access the LoginService service?

Comment: @DanielA.White - Dan, your suggested link led me to use the WCF Service Connection.  I had to tweak it just a bit for my own specific use case, but it is what I needed.  If you will add that as an answer I will mark it accepted.  THanks.